# mySQL complex multitable query

Tags: mysql, multi-table

my problem is that I don't even know if this kind of query is possible. I'll try to explain:

I have two tables regarding telephone calls, "Calls" and "Failed_Calls".

Important columns in both tables are "Destination" and "Route", but there are many more like Id_call and start_date and called_number and so on. I will omit filters regarding time periods to simplify. It is possible to have destinations in "Calls" not present in "Failed_Calls" and vice versa.

I want to get, **for every possible Destination and Route couple, the calls count and the failed calls count**, like the following code:

```
select c.Destination, c.Route, count(c.id_call) as Correct, null as Failed 
from Calls c
where c.Destination like ('Algeria%')
group by c.Destination, c.Route
union all
select f.Destination, f.Route, null, count(f.id_failed_call) as Failed
from Failed_Calls f
where f.Destination like ('Algeria%')
group by f.Destination, f.Route
```

It shows:

```
Destination    Route   Correct   Failed
Algeria        9       1         NULL
Algeria Mobile 9       4         NULL
Algeria Mobile 9       NULL      2
```

...which is correct, but I need to show the data on the two last rows on a single row, i.e., the count of both correct and failed calls for that destination and route.

I have tried with join, left join and with no join but I always get a bad count, something like the product of calls and failed calls for each couple. My best shot until now is:

```
select c.Destination, c.Route, count(distinct(c.id_call)) as Correct,
 count(distinct(f.id_failed_call)) as Failed
from Calls c, Failed_Calls f
where c.Destination like 'Algeria%'
 and f.Destination like 'Algeria%'
group by c.Destination, c.Route
```

...which returns the following:

```
Destination     Route     Correct    Failed
Algeria         9         1          2
Algeria Mobile  9         4          2
```

The "Correct" column is OK but the "Failed" column shows the sum of failed calls for all destinations returned, **in every row** (I have checked this with more destinations in the query).

If this kind of a query is possible, I wish someone could help me with it.

Comment: See CASE, as in SELECT CASE WHEN... THEN... END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it in this case, but I've used a query like this before to sum up data from UNIONs.

```
select Destination, route, sum(Correct), sum(Failed ) from (
    select c.Destination, c.Route, count(c.id_call) as Correct, 0 as Failed 
    from Calls c
    where c.Destination like ('Algeria%')
    group by c.Destination, c.Route
    union all
    select f.Destination, f.Route, 0 as Correct, count(f.id_failed_call) as Failed
    from Failed_Calls f
    where f.Destination like ('Algeria%')
    group by f.Destination, f.Route) as temp_table
group by Destination, route;
```

Comment: This code seems to work. I will test it thoroughly tomorrow. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Something thing like :

```
select c.Destination, c.Route, SUM(c.id_call) as Correct,
SUM(case when f.id_failed_call is NULL then 0 else 1 end)) as Failed
from Calls c, Failed_Calls f
where c.Destination like 'Algeria%'
and f.Destination like 'Algeria%'
group by c.Destination, c.Route
```

Comment: f.id_failed_call is never NULL, it is the table key.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to basically wrap your working query into an outer select, and group the rows there;

```
SELECT Destination, Route,
       COALESCE(SUM(Correct), 0) Correct, COALESCE(SUM(Failed), 0) Failed
FROM (
  SELECT c.Destination, c.Route, COUNT(c.id_call) as Correct, NULL AS Failed 
  FROM Calls c
  WHERE c.Destination like ('Algeria%')
  GROUP BY c.Destination, c.Route
  UNION ALL
  SELECT f.Destination, f.Route, NULL, COUNT(f.id_failed_call) AS Failed
  FROM Failed_Calls f
  WHERE f.Destination LIKE ('Algeria%')
  GROUP BY f.Destination, f.Route
)
GROUP BY Destination, Route;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT dr.DESTINATION,
       dr.ROUTE,
       IFNULL(c.CORRECT_COUNT, 0) AS CORRECT_COUNT,
       IFNULL(f.FAILED_COUNT, 0) AS FAILED_COUNT
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DESTINATION, ROUTE
          FROM CALLS
        UNION DISTINCT
        SELECT DISTINCT DESTINATION, ROUTE
          FROM FAILED_CALLS) dr
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DESTINATION,
                          ROUTE,
                          COUNT(DISTINCT ID_CALL) AS CORRECT_COUNT
                     FROM CALLS
                     GROUP BY DESTINATION, ROUTE) c
    ON (c.DESTINATION = dr.DESTINATION AND
        c.ROUTE = dr.ROUTE)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DESTINATION,
                          ROUTE,
                          COUNT(DISTINCT ID_CALL) AS FAILED_COUNT
                     FROM FAILED_CALLS
                     GROUP BY DESTINATION, ROUTE) f
    ON (f.DESTINATION = dr.DESTINATION AND
        f.ROUTE = dr.ROUTE)
```

The `dr` subquery gets all possible combinations of DESTINATION and ROUTE - the use of UNION DISTINCT indicates that duplicates should be removed.

The `c` subquery then joins in the 'correct' count for each destination and route, if such a count exists.

The `f` subquery then joins in the 'failed' count for each destination and route, if such a count exists.

Sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/907d7/4).

Share and enjoy.